# Matplotlib animated histogram

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to create an animated histogram from my code below. I can create individual histograms for each time however I cannot get the results to be animated with the `matplotlib.animation` function or from emulating the code in the [matplotlib tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/histogram.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


betas = [] # some very long list
entropy = [] # some very long list

for time in [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5,  2.0, 2.5, 3.0 , 3.5,  4.0, 4.5  5.0, 5.5,   6.0, 6.5 , 7.0, 7.5,  8.0 , 8,5 , 9.0, 9.5 , 10.0]:

    plt.figure('entropy distribution at time %s ' % time)        
    indexbetas = {i for i, j in enumerate(betas) if j == time}
    desiredentropies = [x for i, x in enumerate(entropy) if i in indexbetas] #the desiredentropies list depends on time

    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(desiredentropies, 20, alpha=0.75 , label = 'desired entropies')   

plt.xlabel(r"$S_{(\time=%d)}$" % time, fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Frequency of entropies')


plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I am struggling in particular with feeding my `desiredentropies` list which depends on the element in the `time` list for the animation.

Comment: example from tutorial needs a few second by it works for me - Python 2.7.11 & 3.4.3 / Linux Mint 17.  Do you get any error message in console/terminal/cmd.exe ?

Comment: @furas I've added an edit to my OP. My main problem is feeding the updated desiredentropies list I want to make a histogram out of, as time changes. Note: the desiredentropies list changes for each element in time.

Comment: You will have to use `animation.FuncAnimation`

Comment: @furas I understand that as in the example below but how would I update my update_hist to use for the FuncAnimation function in this case.

Comment: `animation.FuncAnimation`  works as `for`. You have to use it instead of `for`. `animation.FuncAnimation` will call your code many times with different value (your time). After every call it make small delay so you can see it as animation.

Comment: @furas It's a bit different. The time list elements are floats not integers and my real time list will have a length of at least a thousand. So a delay won't be ideal either

Answer (score 10):

Try this. This basically just leverages FuncAnimation to let you update the histogram. Check out the [animation documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) to learn more about the various parameters to that function to control the speed of update and stuff like that.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

n = 100
number_of_frames = 10
data = np.random.rand(n, number_of_frames)

def update_hist(num, data):
    plt.cla()
    plt.hist(data[num])

fig = plt.figure()
hist = plt.hist(data[0])

animation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_hist, number_of_frames, fargs=(data, ) )
plt.show()
```

What we do here is call a function, `update_hist` which handles updating the histogram and displaying the new data at each step. We do this by clearing the axis and then indexing into our data with the provided `num`, which is the current frame number.

Comment: How do I update my new desiredentropies list as the list depends on time i.e. the element in the time list?

Comment: Normalize your indices to integers and put the code in your `for` loop into `update_hist`