# how can i turn this plot into bar plots using the same data as i am

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft, pyaudio

basically i would like my frequency spectrum to be in bars varying from frequencies such as  0-200, 200-400, 400-800, 800-2000, 2000-4000 etc etc
im gathering the fft data and plotting it in a standard way real time but i would like it to be a bar chart instead so any help is appreciated!

Here is a gif of what it currently looks like
: https://i.imgur.com/eOGzPFd.gifv

it doesn't really show off the variations in bass and so i would like to group the frequencies into bars some representing a higher range of frequencies ( such as 2000hz-4000hz in one bar ) and some with a lower range of frequencies ( such as 0hz-200hz in one bar )

```py
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
audio_data = 0

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    global audio_data
    audio_data = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
    return None,pyaudio.paContinue


stream = pa.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                 channels=1,
                 rate=44100,
                 output=False,
                 input=True,
                 stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

plt.ion() # Stop matplotlib windows from blocking

# Setup figure, axis and initiate plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ln, = ax.plot([], [], 'b,:')

x = 0

while stream.is_active():

    fft_data = np.fft.fft(audio_data)
    fft_freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft_data),d=1/44100)

    ln.set_xdata(np.abs(fft_freq))
    ln.set_ydata(np.abs(fft_data))


    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

    if x == 0:
        ax.relim()
        ax.autoscale_view()
        ax.set_xlim([-500,10000])
        ax.set_ylim([-1,10])
        x=1

stream.close()
pa.terminate()
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide the underlying data for one time step and make your example work as a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)? Without some example data it is really hard to help you ;-)

Comment: reproducable data isnt really possible as its all real time microphone input, however the data is provided in 2 variables, one for amplitude and one for frequency, the data for one sample i produced is this.  fft amplitude data : [-8.67654419+0.j          2.30658833-3.54092309j  0.44399118-1.41839324j
 ...  0.18584476+0.84690666j  0.44399118+1.41839324j
  2.30658833+3.54092309j]                                                                                                fft frequency data : [   0.           43.06640625   86.1328125  ... -129.19921875  -86.1328125
  -43.06640625]

Comment: And then the amplitude is plotted vs. the frequency right? Could you provide two complete arrays for these by editing your question?

Comment: when i try and print the arrays i get so many results back, including a "..." which i think is just saying theres too much to display, however in that comment i did already seperate the 2 arrays i got

Comment: The "..." is normal behavior of Python for larger arrays. Could you try using `print list(your_array)`, this should print the complete array.

Comment: print list gives me a syntax error any other way?

Comment: Ahh, maybe you need to `print(list(your_array))`. That shouldn't give an error.

Comment: Sound like you want to [animate a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35109034/565489), with custom bins that reflect your desired frequency ranges.

Comment: yes pretty much like this but real time : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpmYtO-xk_I&

Comment: Where you successful with `print(list(your_array))`?

Comment: no it didnt work, i have given up with developing said project as i have handed in the original working version, i just wanted to improve it alot more before i handed it in, but thankyou for the help anyway!